# How to printf part of command line command

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, zcat

Hello I am currently trying to printf a certain part of the command line when i run my program. I currently run my program as follows

```
zcat gcc | sim
```

What i am trying to accomplish is print out to a seperate file the 'gcc' part of the command line. Is there any way to accomplish this. Thanks for the help

I forgot to mention this is in c not C++

Comment: Buddy, google for main function arguments [`argc, argv`]

Comment: it isnt being passed as a main function argument i already tried

Comment: Sorry, could you try to explain again, what you want to do?

Comment: zcat gcc uncompress the file gcc which the program sim reads in and analyses. So i call my program as above. at the end of my program i print out a set of results and want to print out the name of the file that was used which in this case is gcc. However all of the things i have tried just read in the first line of the gcc file and not the explicit command line.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sim' program only knows that it has data from stdin. It doesn't know what is handing the data to stdin - it may be another program, or redirected input, or from a device.

From 'sim' POV, there's only data from stdin.

**IF** you can **guarantee** that you will always receive data from another process via a pipe, you can start looking for process headers matching the 'sim' process, and from then extracting process info from associated processes. However, I suspect that this is more than you're willing to go.

Comment: is there some way to just read in what was typed into the commandline

Comment: There is no 'simple' way. There is a hard way, which would involve you trawling thru' the process tree to find the associated process feeding sim's stdin and then working out the arguments of the assocated process.

Frankly, for what you want to achieve; I'd just extend your "sim" program to have an argument specifying what file to read from. That way you have the name of the file from main()'s argument vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing output of `zcat` (through pipe) to your program, it doesn't know details  of arguments passed to `zcat`.
You can explicitly pass it as a part of input stream though,

```
(echo 'zcat gcc'; zcat gcc ) | sim
```

but that is a hack. It may be Ok if you are planning to run your 
program this way only.